# react native -expo: is there a way to print the location on phone's screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Is there a way to print something on my phone screen?

I tried to print the "location" on the screen when I got the location change.

In my example, I try to use the `TaskManager` of `expo` because I have to run some background service and I want to check if this method work or not while the app is killed.

This is my code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

const LOCATION_TASK_NAME = 'background-location-task';

export default class Component extends React.Component {
  onPress = async () => {
    const { status } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
    if (status === 'granted') {
      await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, {
        accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Balanced,
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
      style={{alignItems: "center",paddingTop:100}}
       onPress={this.onPress}>
        <Text>Enable background location</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

TaskManager.defineTask(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, ({ data, error }) => {
  if (error) {
    // Error occurred - check `error.message` for more details.
    return;
  }
  if (data) {
    const { locations } = data;

    // do something with the locations captured in the background
    // HERE I WANT TO PRINT THE "locations" INTO MY PHONE SCREEN 


  }
});
```